# from .forms import RegisterForm error

Tags: python, django

I got following error

> from .forms import RegisterForm
>   ImportError: cannot import name RegisterForm

I cannot understand . of from "." forms.
What does `.` mean?

I think I can resolve this error when i can understand `.` mean.
Now, I write `urls.py` of `accounts` app,

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from .forms import RegisterForm


def index(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context)


def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/regist.html', context)


@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('main:index')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/regist.html', context)
```

What should i do to fix?

Answer (score 0):

`from .forms import RegisterForm`

in this case means the same as:

`from accounts.forms import RegisterForm`.

From your description, you have something like:

```
accounts/
   forms.py
   urls.py  <-- the file you listed in your question
```

so python is expecting to find `class RegisterForm` in `forms.py`.

The error means you either don't have the file, or the class is not in it, I would suspect.

Comment: Why would they write the tutorial like that?  At least write `your_app.forms` so beginners know what to replace.